# Web push library is failing to Create web push notification in Google Chrome with error type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'

Tags: java, google-chrome, mozilla, web-push

I want to send push notification from java library called Web-push library for java. It is Working file in firefox but when it comes to Google Chrome then it failed to Subscribe the push manager with following.

### Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'

Here are the code and my folder structure of the project.

Before I have tried the same code for google chrome that time it is executed properly. That time it won't authorize the for Mozilla Firefox, That was the server-side error I figured out.

```
async function subscribe() {
const response =  await fetch('./VapidPublicKey');
const vapidPublicKey =  await response.text();
console.log(vapidPublicKey);
    const convertedVapidKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(vapidPublicKey);
    var browserOptions={};
    if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'){
       browserOptions={userVisibleOnly: true};
    }else{
          browserOptions={
               userVisibleOnly: true,
               applicationServerKey: convertedVapidKey
           };   
    }
       navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function 
    (serviceWorkerRegistration)
       {
       serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.
        subscribe(browserOptions).then(function 
        (subscription) {
              return sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
             })
             .catch(function (e) {
                if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
                   console.warn('Permission for Notifications was denied');
                    } else {
                  alert('Unable to subscribe to push.'+ e);
                 }
            });
        });
        }
        </code>
       </pre>'
    ##And below is code for conversion from base64url to uint8Array ##'
    <pre><code>
      async function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String){
        const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
      const base64 = (base64String + padding)
      .replace(/\-/g, '+')
     .replace(/_/g, '/');

      const rawData = window.atob(base64);
      const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
         outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
       }
      console.log("output array is : "+outputArray);
         return outputArray;
        }
     </code>
     </pre>
```

### Folder structure

```
RootFolder
       |-WebCOntent
            |-index.html
            |-main.js
            |-sw.js
            |-manifest.json
```

The exception I am getting

### TypeError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': The provided value is not of type '(ArrayBuffer or ArrayBufferView)'

I have Resolved above type error 
below code worked for me

const urlB64ToUint8Array = (base64String)=>{
    const padding = "=".repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
      outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}

Comment: I have resolved Google Chrome Exception I am passing key but it is always returning null, my mistake was in the conversation of base64 keys.